# Shutdown all Akka actors on a system

Tags: akka

My understanding is that even if you Ctrl-C, Akka can have some processes and actors still running.  How can I, using the command line only, shutdown all remaining Akka processes and actors? I'd like to do this at the shell, not by writing Scala code.

Comment: You have tried what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `SIGINT` (ctrl + c) a process, you'll kill the JVM. If you kill the JVM, you've killed Akka – it doesn't spawn any processes outside of the VM. If you want to programmatically you should call `shutdown` and `awaitTermination` on your `ActorSystem`. Here's more docs about [ActorSystem](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/?_ga=1.124749256.350209094.1396869304#akka.actor.ActorSystem)

Comment: I think a ctrl + c will send a SIGINT. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

Answer (score 1):

If by hitting Ctrl-C for some reason doesn't stop akka, try again. As long as you exit the JVM, it should be good.

But, if you have this problem (akka no stopping), there might something in your code that's preventing it to stop